# What is the recommended way to validate subscriptions using Unity IAP with the new Google Play Billing library?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-play-services

The newly available Google Play Billing library [does not support](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/unity#subscription-manager) the `SubscriptionManager` of Unity IAP.

Usually, I would validate the receipt with the `SubscriptionManager` and check the `is_subscribed`, `is_expired`, etc attributes and act accordingly.

The documentation of Unity is not up to date with this new information. The Google Play Billing documentation offer no solution or insight as to how to validate that a subscription is still valid. "Not supported" is hardly a valid response, subscriptions are part of a lot of games and software made with Unity.

How can I validate that a Google Play subscription is valid and not expired in a Unity Project using the Unity IAP. Failing to be able to use Unity IAP, any other solution or insight is welcome.

Answer (score 2):

It appears that this new plugin makes it mandatory to validate user subscriptions server-side. When implementing the plugin, I had to create a back-end service that provided the expiry date back to our app since we couldn't use `SubscriptionManager` to grab that information anymore.

I can't really recommend a specific way of doing this, because everyone's back-end will be different. For us, we utilize [Docker](https://www.docker.com/) containers on [DigitalOcean](https://www.digitalocean.com/) droplets that our app and database can communicate with. This allows us to have a centralized location for back-end services, which we write in Python using [Flask](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/).

We have set up one that can go through our database, find every subscription that has expired based on the saved DateTime, and validate whether it has renewed or not. We added an extra endpoint to that service for grabbing the expiry date of a Google Play subscription, as mentioned above.

Subscription information can be obtained by accessing the Google Play REST API's [purchases.subscriptions.get](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/rest/v3/purchases.subscriptions/get). This will return a [SubscriptionPurchase](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/rest/v3/purchases.subscriptions#SubscriptionPurchase) object, which provides relevant information that you can then process to find out attributes such as `is_subscribed`, `is_expired`, etc.

It may be possible to send this directly from your Unity app/game, however this may also make man-in-the-middle attacks possible (admittedly my knowledge in this area isn't quite there, so I recommend you do your own reading on this).

---

Also as just a general suggestion, I recommend you try to post questions across both here and the UnityIAP sub-forum. The UnityIAP support folks are super active and even if they can't help because this is a Google implementation, it should definitely put it on their radar! I try to post there whenever I can as it allows them to make improvements to UnityIAP. (:

Answer (score 0):

Yes at the moment we should use server-side API for getting Subscription related info. As SubscriptionManger was dependent on developer payload which is deprecated. See 2nd para https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/developer-payload